# When do the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix belong to its field?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, field-theory, symmetric-matrices

Every polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix (see [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)). Therefore, the eigenvalues of a matrix over a field $\mathbb F$ must belong to $\mathbb F$ if, and only if, $\mathbb F$ is [algebraically closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field).

However, the eigenvalues of a real **symmetric** matrix are always real, despite $\mathbb R$ being not algebraically closed. What is up with that?

Typically, the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix over a field $\mathbb F$ are not required to belong to $\mathbb F$. Indeed, the matrix
$$X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},$$
which can be taken over any field, have eigenvalues $0$ and $\pm\sqrt2$, so $\mathbb Q$ (as well as a bunch of finite fields) have not this property. Is there a nice way to characterize the fields with it? What is special about $\mathbb R$?

Comment: The fact that the eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix are always real comes down to the interaction between the matrix and a certain "sesquilinear" form. In particular: if $X$ has eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ and associated eigenvector $v \in \Bbb C^n$, then with the sesquilinear form $\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_j x_j \bar y_j$, we can deduce that 
$$
\bar \lambda \langle v,v \rangle = \overline{\langle Av, v \rangle} = \langle v, Av \rangle = \langle Av, v \rangle = \lambda \langle v,v \rangle.
$$
So, we are forced to conclude that $\lambda = \bar \lambda$.

Comment: So, there are a few special things about $\Bbb R$ here: the completion of $\Bbb R$ is a degree-2 extension. The $\Bbb R$-linear form $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ was able to be defined in such a way that $\langle v,v \rangle = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$ (which relies on $\Bbb R$ being zero-characteristic, and possibly on $\Bbb R$ being ordered). Once we had this form, matrices that are self-adjoint relative to this bilinear form (so not only symmetric matrices but also Hermitian matrices) are guaranteed to have real eigenvalues.

Comment: This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.